# How I connect 4 gang wifi switch?

Tags: electrical, switch, wifi

[image]I'm well aware of the risk of replacing in wrong way switch box. I will not change the switch box by myself and I will ask an expert to do the job.

For my personal experience I would like to know how to install this particular WiFi switch in Australia.

all the lights are connected to a transformers for 12v lights
all the neutral are insulated together

the second switch of the living room doesn't exist anymore, its been removed and closed in the wall. so I will need only a one way switch for the living room.

thanks guys

[image: electrical]

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: "this particular WiFi switch in **Australia**" -- from the OP, emphasis added. _gets @ThreePhaseEel a 2nd cup of coffee_ ;)

Comment: You note that a switch "has been removed and closed in the wall". I'm sure there are code differences between the US and Australia, but in the US, making a _permanent_ closure over spliced joints (which is what is likely left after a switch is removed) is against code. You have to have access because splices can come loose. Please double check that this is allowed by code where you live - maybe inform your electrician of the work already done and have him/her confirm that it's safe/meets code.

Comment: @FreeMan It's not allowed there either.  The single wires depicted on the 2-ways (3-ways) also are not Code (I'm not worried about neutral or ground, those are shown).  There's a remote-powered 3-way in here too. This looks poorly thought out at every level.

Answer (score 3):

### Send this switch back

This is cheap Cheese junk dumped onto your shores, illegal and unsafe for its purpose, and the seller knew that and took your money nonetheless.  **Send it back**.

The various logos on it are the ones they stick on all their fakes. None represent a real testing lab. The fact is the switch will cause safety problems, and if anything else causes a safety problem, this switch will make things much worse.  E.G. the plastic it's made of will burn like a freak and start a fire in the walls, while emitting toxic fumes, not self-extinguish like the correct (but expensive) plastic.  100 details like that are what makes safe switches safe.

Don’t buy junk for use in AC mains. And  buying mail-order *is* buying junk, especially Amazon Marketplace.

Companies use direct mail-order because it allows them to sneak illegal stuff around the safety schemes that keep dangerous junk out of your retail shops. Somehow Amazon Marketplace sneaks around this too, even when it dropships from an Amazon warehouse. If you have a retail chain of brick-and-mortar stores, mail-ordering *from them* is usually pretty safe as they typically just offer the same selection.  They can also do curbside pickup if COVID is an issue.

### A switch like it still won't work with that remote 2-way (3-way).

That switch is designed to replace four 1-way switches. Dining and kitchen are 1-way switches.  The living room switch is one-way *now*... However...

The "Entrance" switch is a 2-way (US: 3-way) **that is powered from the far end**.  In other words, *this* switch works just like *the switch you just took out*.

There is no way for a 1-way switch at this location to interact with that 2-way, except using a rather advanced technique called a relay.  If you want to smart-switch control that switch, you'll need to put a smart switch at the other end, and in this box, put whatever *that other smart switch* needs to interact with, probably its partner smart switch.   And again, buy quality products from local shops that have passed AU safety standards so they don't burn your house down.

Comment: Thanks for the information guys ! Now I know much more !